# How to correctly version a modified package?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, deja-dup, lintian

Currently I'm modifying the deja-dup backup tool, my inglorious attempts are documented under: https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/76645 and my source-branch can be found under: [lp:~beowulfof/+junk/deja-dup](https://code.launchpad.net/~beowulfof/+junk/deja-dup).

Basically, what I did was add options for asynchronous upload for remote filesystems and a setting to manually choose the size of the backup files, instead of just using 5/25MiB (I think the user should be able to decide by himself).

But my problem is not, about the changes, it is about the version to build a package. While in development of the patch, I just incremented the version number to `33.ubuntu3`, whereas the original package has `32.0-0ubuntu5`.

I want to build a package and that to my PPA, but therefore I wanted to change according to the [packaging guide](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage) to `32.0_0ubuntu5ppa1`.

If I try to build the source package by `bzr builddeb -S -- -us -uc` it claims the following:

```
bzr: ERROR: Inconsistency between source format and version: version is not native, format is native.
```

So, what version should I set the package to, before building it for the PPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because the `debian/source/format` file says that this is a `3.0 (native)` package.

As a bit of background info, the `debian/source/format` file describes the format of the package. There are three formats available:

- `1.0`: Specifies that the `debian` folder and any changes that need to be made to other files in the upstream package will be in a `.diff.gz` file. This results in a `.orig.tar.gz` that contains the upstream tarball and `.diff.gz` that includes changes/additions for packaging.
- `3.0 (quilt)`: Specifies that the `debian` folder in a `.debian.tar.gz` file, and that changes to the upstream files will be specified as separate patch files in the `debian/patches` folder, and will use the quilt patch system.
- `3.0 (native)`: Same as `3.0 (quilt)`, but for packages that won't have any patches because the software/program itself is made by the distributors (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.), and so any changes are made directly to the files.

For the last two formats, the versioning formats are different. `3.0 (quilt)` expects the version number followed by `-#` or `-#ubuntu#`. Some examples of this are `2.7-1ubuntu3` (from Ubuntu's standpoint, this means that the package was imported from Debian, but has Ubuntu-specific changes on top of it) and `3.4-2` (from Ubuntu's standpoint, this means that the package was imported from Debian, but has *no* Ubuntu-specific changes).  Note that the version doesn't necessarily indicate whether there are changes made to the upstream tarball itself (patch files in `debian/patches`), or whether they're just changes in building the package.

For `3.0 (native)`, there is no dash after the version. Some examples of this are `23` and `8.4`.

In your case, the version follows the `3.0 (quilt)` format, but `debian/source/format` says `3.0 (native)`. There are two things you need to do here:

1. Change `debian/source/format` to `3.0 (quilt)`.
2. (Recommended) Make any changes to the package in a separate patch. Take a look at Ubuntu's [patches](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/deja-dup/vivid/files/head:/debian/) folder for the syntax. Note that the `series` file specifies what patches in the folder should be applied and in what order. (lines starting with `#` are ignored)

As for the version of your package, using `32.0-0ubuntu5ppa1` will work (watch the underscores and dashes).